# Why in Django many-to-many relation shows wrong data in the admin panel

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement the many-to-many relation to support in the user model these features:

1. user followers (persons who follows the user)
2. user following (persons the user follows)

To achieve that I'm using double relation on the same model because followers/following are the same User models.
Basically it works hoverwer I'm facing a weird behavior in the Django admin panel. When I add some user to other user to the **following** list (in the shell everything ok), the Django admin panel shows that user in the **followers** list but he should be in the **following** list. I can't understand why it happens.

Many thanks for any help!

My models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True,related_name='user_followers',symmetrical=False)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True,related_name='user_following',symmetrical=False)
    pass
```

Supppose Admin wants to follow Neo. Neo should have follower - Admin. Admin - should have Neo in his *following* list.
Shell commands and result:

```
admin = User.objects.filter(username='admin')[0]
neo = User.objects.filter(username='neo_anderson')[0]


// check that everything is empty
neo.user_following.all()
<QuerySet []>
neo.user_followers.all()
<QuerySet []>


// --- admin wants to follow neo ---

// add the admin to the neo followers
 neo.user_followers.add(admin)
 neo.save()

// add the neo to the admin following 
admin.user_following.add(neo)
admin.save()

// check if admin follows Neo
admin.user_following.contains(neo)  
TRUE

// check if neo has the follower admin
neo.user_followers.contains(admin)      
TRUE
```

But in the admin panel I see that for the user **Admin** the user **Neo** is in the **followers** section but it should be **following** because Admin wants to follow Neo. Not vice versa

[image: admin_screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use:
admin = User.objects.get(username='admin') to avoid having a list, that you need to index... (cleaner)

Second:
I am not sure how the "related_name" property is working exactly and how it would behave, but have you tried switching / using the opposite? I would assume followers would follow "me", meaning they have the following attribute, instead of the followers attribute!?

Maybe I am wrong, but try:

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True,related_name='user_following',symmetrical=False)
following = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True,related_name='user_followers',symmetrical=False)
```

(remember to migrate those changes to the database)

I would be curious what the behavior is then, please let me know

Comment: Thank you @EvilSmurf for your idea. related_name just reflects the opposite link in the foreign model. I was confused because of the trying to set 2 many-to-many relations in the same model. I've tried to change the related_name to the opposite values and it works. Hovewer I still can't normally figure out in my mind and I really curious about some explanation from someone who deeply understands how it works. P.S. thank you for the **object.get** remark!